# How can use firebase url shortener in python Django?

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Is there any way to use firebase URL shortener(dynamic links) programmatically in Python Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a specific library, but you could call the REST API to generate links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#using_the_rest_api